# How to set up paths of MSBuild tool for Jenkins?

Tags: windows, jenkins, msbuild

I am trying to automatically build a software using Visual Studio's MSBuild tool. The issue is: Jenkins cannot find it.

My first attempt was to add the MSBuild.exe path to the environment variable `PATH`. Great, that works. But then NuGet was missing, so I had to download nugget.exe and put its path to `PATH` as well.

But now I am facing an issue I probably cannot solve easily. It cannot find `CL.exe`. Even if I add it, there are other things missing.
So I did some research and found out about the vcvarsall.bat.

In my Jenkinsfile I tried something like this:

```
stages {
  stage('Set up paths') {
    steps {
      bat '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat x86"'
    }
  }

  stage('Build') {
    steps {
      bat 'msbuild myProject.vcxproj /p:configuration=debug /p:platform=win32
    }
  }
}
```

But this does not work. MSBuild and CL.exe not found. I also tried to use `call` and put them in one stage like this:

```
  stage('Build') {
    steps {
      bat '''
        call "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat x86"
        call msbuild myProject.vcxproj /p:configuration=debug /p:platform=win32
      '''
    }
  }
```

But it won't work either.

Now I am trying to get the vcvarsall run at boot time, but calling it does not effect new instances of cmd as it seems.

What can I do now? How can I set up those variables for a Jenkins build slave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that calling the vcvarsall in another step won't work at all. But calling them in the same bat statement as the msbuild it works. **But**: There are different vcvars files in different locations.

Since I only need 32 bit compilation (due to some old components...) I simply run the following Jenkinsfile with success:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                bat '''
                    call "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars32.bat"
                    msbuild MsBuildTest.sln
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a better way would be to do something "vcvars32.bat" && "remaining script". Example:

```
environment {
    VS_TOOLS="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\Tools"
    VS_MSBUILDCMD="${VS_TOOLS}\\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"
    VS_DEVCMD="${VS_TOOLS}\\VSDevCmd.bat"
}
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        echo Performing unit tests"
        bat label: 'Test Components', script: "\"${VS_DEVCMD}\" && vstest.console.exe /Platform:x64 /logger:trx;LogFileName=\"TestResult.trx\" \"TestComponent.dll\""
    }
}
```